# Win32 call SendMessage recursively

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, message-queue, sendmessage

as the below code shown, for the customized message *WM_TESTMSG* handler, it call **SendMessage** to send the same message. And I think there will be a **Stack Overflow exception** and the *MessageBeep* will not be called, because SendMessage will call the WindowProc directly. But When I test the code, it works well! 
**Why no exception?** Thanks!

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define WM_TESTMSG (WM_USER + 0x100)
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(IN HWND hWnd, IN UINT uMsg, IN WPARAM wParam, IN LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT ret = 0;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TESTMSG, 0, 0);
            break;
        }

        case WM_TESTMSG:
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TESTMSG, 0, 0);
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);  // I think the program can't run to here
            break;
        }

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            ret = ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}



BOOL RegisterWndClass(IN HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndClassEx;

    ZeroMemory(&wndClassEx, sizeof(wndClassEx));
    wndClassEx.cbSize = sizeof (wndClassEx);
    wndClassEx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClassEx.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wndClassEx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClassEx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClassEx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClassEx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_HAND));
    wndClassEx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    wndClassEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
    wndClassEx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClassEx.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyMainWnd");
    wndClassEx.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ERROR));

    return ::RegisterClassEx(&wndClassEx);
}


int WINAPI WinMain(IN HINSTANCE hInstance, IN HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    RegisterWndClass(hInstance);

    HWND hMainWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MyMainWnd", L"MainWnd", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, 0, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hMainWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Using this above approach, I do get a stack overflow (as expected).

Comment: How should we know what else you are doing besides `MainWndProc`? Maybe your code doesn't even enter `MainWndProc`. Please edit the code to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I have updated a completed sample code.The code is very simple.  For WM_TESTMSG case, I think there is a recursion. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it in Visual Studio 2015 and it fails as expected.

Comment: Build in VS 2017 and also getting stack overflow. Maybe you are running older version of the executable?

Comment: Hi, my compiler is VS2015. **And i got a stack overflow exception if runing the test code on Win7 X64, but works well on Win10 RS3 x64.** Maybe there are some difference between Win7 and Win10 for this case. Thank you!

Comment: What is RS3? I have Win10 version 1709. Evidently that's the fall creator which we have heard so many bad things about. Did you install your Win10 update manually?

Comment: Yeah, Win10 RS3 is the 1709 version. For my PC, Windows automatically updated to 1709.

Comment: Win10 v1709 here too. I build again with VS2015 x86/x64, debug and relase. Sample code crashes in all cases.